# How to listen for conversation timeout in weld/seam

Tags: seam, seam-conversation, weld

Currently working on an application which contains multiple tabbed conversations. When a conversation times out I want to close the tab associated with that conversation.

Is there a way to listen for a conversation timeout or do I just have to keep polling and checking to see if the conversation has timed out?

Answer (score 0):

```
@Destroy @Remove
public void destroy() {
  //Close tabs
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Destroy annotation for the conversion scoped bean method where you want to know that the conversation is time out or ended.